# Change manifest.plist values in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, manifest

I have a manifest.plist file (come from Apple). This is an XML file.
Here's an exemple of the structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>id</key>
    <string>3214</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <dict>
      <key>en</key>
      <string>Hello World</string>
      <key>jp</key>
      <string>Hello World JP</string>
    </dict>
    <key>kilometers</key>
    <integer>430</integer>
    <key>cloud</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I can get this XML as object with simplexml. Now I would like to change some values in my XML (e.g cloud to false of jp string value).

Comment: OK, but what is your question? Is it just how to edit the XML? Then searching `php edit xml` will give you everything you need

Comment: Now I tried with DOMElement and Xpath query '/plist/dict/key[4]' to get the cloud key. But How can change its value to false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I tried with DOMElement and Xpath query '/plist/dict/key[4]' to get the cloud key. But How can change its value to false ?

The element you talk about is here:

```
    <key>cloud</key>
    <true/>
```

And you want to change from `<true/>` to `<false/>`. However that is *not* changing the value but replacing the `<true/>` element node with a new node, a `<false/>` element node.

This is not (really) possible with `SimpleXML` because it can not replace nodes.

With `DomDocument` you can do it with the [`DOMNode::replaceChild()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/DOMNode.replaceChild) function.

An example:

Let's assume you have the variable `$key` and it is the `<key>` element you've fetched via xpath.

```
$true  = $key->nextSibling;
$false = $key->ownerDocument->createElement('false');
$key->parentNode->replaceChild($false, $true);
```