# SimpleXML multidimensional nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML like this:

```
<properties>
  <property>name</property><value>john</value>
  <property>surname</property><value>wayne</value>
  <property>age</property><value>33</value>
  <property>blaaa</property><value>blaa</value>
</properties>
```

I have to parse this and I used something like this:

```
$xle = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');
foreach ($xle->properties as $properties) {
    foreach ($properties->property as $property) {
        echo $property, "<br />\n";
    }
    foreach ($properties->value as $value) {
        echo $value, "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

I came to this so far, i need something like

"property = value" 
   "name = john"

my code outputs something like this :

```
name
surname
age
blaa
john
wayne
33
blaa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each value is a *following sibling* to the property element. You can express that with xpath quite easily:

```
following-sibling::value[1]
```

will give you the `<value>` element if the `<property>` element is the context-node.

Getting the context-node with SimpleXML is rather straight forward, so here is the example PHP code:

```
$properties = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');

foreach($properties->property as $property)
{
    list($value) = $property->xpath('following-sibling::value[1]');
    echo $property, " = ", $value, "\n";
}
```

The output for the example XML then is:

```
name = john
surname = wayne
age = 33
blaaa = blaa
```

[Online Demo](http://eval.in/12537)

This looks similar to a properties file (plist) for which I know of a related Q&A from memory, so it's maybe interesting as well to you:

- [Change manifest.plist values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15291969/367456)

Comment: @michi: Just FYI: PHP 5.4 is without `list()`: `$value = $property->xpath('following-sibling::value[1]')[0];` ;) + thx

Answer (score 1):

I agree, a weird format, but valid. Given that every `<property>` is followed by its `<value>`, go...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xmlfile.xml');

$prop = $xml->xpath('//property');
$value = $xml->xpath('//value');

$count=count($prop)-1;

for ($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++) {
    echo $prop[$i].": ".$value[$i]."<br />";;
}
```

---> live demo: http://3v4l.org/0CS73

Comment: I agree (+1), but why not just drop `$count=count($prop)-1;` & do `for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)` ?

Comment: @Wrikken ah, wait a minute, your codesample doesn't make sense, because `$count` isn't set. if `count()`is executed with every iteration --> performance

Comment: Erm, sorry, I meant `$count=count($prop)` & `foreach($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)`, my apologies. You are of course totally correct of not having `count()` in the `for`.

Comment: @Wrikken no problem. I guess if the xml has just a few nodes, like in his example, performance is ok with `count()` in the loop. a real big xml though...

Comment: Just the `-1` to have `<=` instead of `<` struck me as curious ;)